# Best way to render dynamic sitemap - react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, sitemap

I am a beginner in react and I have made a portfolio website using react frontend.

I wanted to add a dynamic sitemap to the application and almost tried every possible way given on youtube, stackoverflow and google. But, I couldn't do what I wanted like if I add a new portfolio, it will not be there in the sitemap.

###### Things I already tried:-

- At first, I added a `sitemap.xml` file in the public folder with all static contents but there was the same problem, I had to build whole application everytime I add a portfolio and also I will have to manually change the sitemap.
- I also tried `react-snap` and `react-snap-sitemap` together which mostly worked but then, for some pages, I don't know why but the `css` stopped working. Mostly it happened with the pages which I didn't want in the sitemap or I didn't want them to be crawled.
- Then, I also tried a way where there was a `sitemap-generator.js` which we would have to run to create a `sitemap.xml` file in the `build` folder, but then, we would have to build it again and again, and a bigger issue was that it used babel scripts which was giving errors.
- Then I finally found out `react-dynamic-sitemap` which works almost perfectly but the issue is that it is rendering the component `Sitemap` and not a file `sitemap.xml`.
  So, the `xml` content is displayed as text.
  I also found out ways to display it as xml content but I was unable to do so.
  I assume that this sitemap could not be submitted to google and also, this is not working as purely dynamic.
  Because, for the portfolio details pages, I have to pass slugs in the `slugs` parameter like this: `[{id: "foo"}, {id: "bar"}]`. I tried to bring these from the database but even if I use `.then()` and then load the `Routes` after the portfolios data is fetched from the server, it gives error as it has to be loaded in other `Sitemap` component till then.

###### Code for `react-dynamic-sitemap`:-

Sitemap.js

```
import React from "react";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import DynamicSitemap from "react-dynamic-sitemap";

export default function Sitemap(props) {
    return (
        <DynamicSitemap routes={Routes} prettify={true} {...props}/>
    );
}
```

Routes.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Portfolio } from './PortfolioComponent/Portfolio';
import { PortfolioDetail } from './PortfolioDetailComponent/PortfolioDetail';
import Sitemap from './Sitemap';

const MyRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            ...Other Static Routes...
            <Route
                path="/portfolio"
                element={<Portfolio />}
                sitemapIndex='true'
                changefreq='weekly'
                priority='1'
            />
            <Route
                path="/portfolio/:slug"
                element={<PortfolioDetail />}
                sitemapIndex='true'
                changefreq='weekly'
                priority='1'
                slugs={[Objects of the slugs of different portfolios have to written staticly]}
            />
            <Route path="/sitemap" element={<Sitemap />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default MyRoutes;
```

Can someone please answer these points, and *end the issue for all React developers*:-

- What is the best way to generate sitemaps staticly in react, as many solutions say to use nextjs or to use online sitemaps generator
- If no other way possible, how can we render `react-dynamic-sitemap` content as `xml`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you are using Create React App (CRA), right?

I have to be honest, CRA is easy to get started, but as you scale up and require more advanced features (e.g. image optimization, sitemap generation, SEO, etc), as you may have already noticed, you will start finding it problematic.

Since you want to have a sitemap, indicating your site is starting to grow into a decent size, instead of digging the rabbit hole, I would suggest you move to a more scalable framework, which Next.js is one of the most popular ones.

That being said, be warned that even Next.js doesn't have native support to sitemap. Most people just rely on `next-sitemap`, but it is proven to be a robust solution

Comment: Yes I am using using CRA, and now agree that migrating to nextjs will be a great idea, thanks for your answer, and so I think we can conclude that there is exactly no official way to add a dynamic sitemap to react :(